# Counting shapes by name in Visio

Tags: vba, visio

I want to **count different types of shapes** in my diagram, and I can't seem to get that done. I think I have to code something for that.
I use **Visio 2007** for that.

I have a flow chart with mostly process shapes that I want to **distinguish by name**. E.g "Type A", "Type B". And at the end, I want to have a list that tells me how often I used Type A and Type B. Counting by hand will be to error prone.

I already checked out the report/statistic function (I'm using it in German, so I'm afraid I can't tell you the exact menu name), where you can define a report function by yourself, although that one misses features for my needs. I managed to make a report for my shapes, but only when they all are selected. But when the user has to select them by hand, then he can count them as well right from the start... And you have to make 4-5 clicks in order to get that static report result.

Another almost useful function I found was the layer method: Create a layer for the types I want to count, and then assign the shapes to that layer. But, again, this is too error prone. If the user misses a shape, the count will be wrong.

So I think I will need to code something with the VBA.
Additionally, I'd like to have a **text field next to my diagram** where the resulting **counts for all types are always displayed**. So that you see when you add a shape of Type A that the count goes up by one.

Could anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myShape As Shape

Sub ShapesDetails()

    Call DeleteShapes(True)

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 139.5, 81.75, 72, 72).Select
    Selection.Name = "Rectangle"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeSmileyFace, 252.75, 71.25, 72, 72).Select
    Selection.Name = "Smiley Face"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Call ShapeDetails(True)

End Sub

Sub ShapeDetails(x As Boolean)
    For Each myShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        MsgBox "Shape name: " & myShape.Name & vbTab & " Shape type: " & myShape.Type
    Next
End Sub

Sub DeleteShapes(x As Boolean)
    For Each myShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        myShape.Delete
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Data= reports = advanced to configure a report to count objects with your custom shape Property (e.g. 'MIO') && exists. (Or another field, many to choose from). I set all the boxes i wanted to count to have property 'MIO'=TRUE, and then chose to display property Displayed Text. It takes some fiddling around in the Subtotals dialog and options in the next window to get the count looking nice. Leave COUNT unticked, and in the options dialog enable 'show all values' and tick 'exclude duplicate rows from group'.

Outputs as XML  Excel  Viso object. I know for the visio object, to update report, right click on it =Run report.

HTH